# GWT JsInterop - call an object like it's a function

Tags: gwt

Using JsInterop, I've wrapped the following JavaScript code:

```
var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
    .clipExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]]);
```

as follows:

```
private Voronoi voronoi;
...
voronoi = d3.geom().voronoi()
          .clipExtent(new Double[][] {{0.D, 0.D}, {width, height}});
```

This much appears to be working.

Later on, on the JavaScript side of things, they make the following call:

```
path = path
  .data(voronoi(vertices), polygon);
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to call my voronoi instance as if it's a function in this way.

In this document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10fmlEYIHcyead_4R1S5wKGs1t2I7Fnp_PaNaa7XTEk0/edit#, I'm seeing the following line:

@JsFunction
Another powerful feature of JsInterop is the ability to represent JavaScript function contracts between Java and JavaScript. That means a JavaScript function can be easily called from Java or **a Java object can be called like a function in JavaScript:**

Right now my Voronoi object is the following:

```
@JsType(isNative = true)
public interface Voronoi extends Geometry {

    <D> Voronoi clipExtent(D[][] bounds);
}
```

Any ideas what I need to do to call my Voronoi instance as if it's a function?

Thank you

Comment: "a Java object can be called like a function in JavaScript" - I may be wrong but guess this statement is about anonymous classes/lambdas, think callbacks, not any class to function

Answer (score 0):

```
@JsType(isNative = true)
public interface Voronoi extends Geometry {

    @JsMethod
    static native [TheTypeItReturns] call(Voronoi self, [ParameterTypes]... args);

    <D> Voronoi clipExtent(D[][] bounds);
}
```

Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply .